# Using a static script tag in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the default starting project from `create-react-app`, with the following folder structure:

```
app
--public
----index.html
--src
----App.js
----components
-------map.js
```

I have included an external CDN library in the `index.html` body tag. However, I'm confused about how to use the methods of this library in my `map.js` component.

Just writing the library methods in my `map.js`, returns:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/map.js
  Line 5:  'L' is not defined  no-undef
```

Is there any way I can include a JS CDN library in my React components without actually importing the library as `React Component` via `npm install`?

Comment: How did you include the library? Did it include it before the bundle file?

Comment: I still haven't run `npm build` on my app. I'm in the dev process, if that is what you are asking? Does this means that I will have to bundle every time I save in order for the CDN library to be available?

Comment: @BlueBird03 Is there no npm package of that library?

Comment: Please show the `<script>` definitions from your `index.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading a component in the DOM, React has no knowledge of the DOM. So you need to create a wrapper component for the DOM library and use the `ref` prop to access it. If you're a beginner please use React libraries exclusively, if you need third party libraries, start by reading the React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html about third party libraries.

Btw, the error you're seeing is most likely a babel error which can't transform your ES6 classes, it can't find the library you require. I think there are options to configure global environment, so it ignores these errors (but that probably means ejecting from cra).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this link:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder

> To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use a special
>   variable called PUBLIC_URL.
>
> Inside index.html, you can use it like this:
>
> Only files
>   inside the public folder will be accessible by %PUBLIC_URL% prefix. If
>   you need to use a file from src or node_modules, you’ll have to copy
>   it there to explicitly specify your intention to make this file a part
>   of the build.
>
> When you run npm run build, Create React App will substitute
>   %PUBLIC_URL% with a correct absolute path so your project works even
>   if you use client-side routing or host it at a non-root URL.
>
> In JavaScript code, you can use process.env.PUBLIC_URL for similar
>   purposes:

It will show you how to do it the way create-react-app prefers.